# How can I keep the parent from displaying when the child is filtered out?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my repeater:

```
<div ng-controller="EventController">
    <div class="input-group" id="search">
        <label>Search:</label><input type="text" id="searchField" class="form-control" ng-model="search" /><br />
        <select id="searchByDate" class="form-control" ng-model="dateFilter">
            <option value="">Filter by Month</option>
            @{
                foreach (DateTime month in ViewBag.Months)
                {
                    <option value="@month.ToString("yyyy-MM")">@month.ToString("MMMM yyyy")</option>
                }
            }
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="margin: 0; padding: 0" ng-repeat="DateBegin in events|groupBy:'DateBegin'|filter: dateFilter"><br />
        <h2 style="padding: 0" margin: 0;>{{ DateBegin | date:'medium' }}</h2><br />
        <div class="row tableCell" ng-repeat="event in events | filter: { DateBegin: DateBegin } | filter: search">
            <a href="/EventDetails/{{ event.ID }}"><h1>{{ event.Name }}</h1></a>
            <p>{{ event.Description }}</p>
            <ul>
                <li>Time Begin: {{ event.TimeBegin }}</li>
                <li>Duration: {{ event.Duration }}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
    function EventController($scope, $http) {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '//localhost:60009/api/event'
        })
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.events = data;
        })
        .error(function (data) {
        });
    }

    var uniqueDates = function (data, key) {
        var result = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var value = data[i][key];
            if (result.indexOf(value) == -1) {
                result.push(value);
            }
        }
        return result;
    };

    myApp.filter('groupBy',
            function () {
                return function (collection, key) {
                    if (collection === null) return;
                    return uniqueDates(collection, key);
                };
            });
</script>
```

This works exactly as I had hoped, minus a bit of formatting. Events are grouped by date, and the date selector can filter months, and the search box filters event details. Here is my only problem:

**Before Filtering (looking good):**

[image]

**After Filtering (empty dates still appear - in this picture, I want May 23 to go away):**

[image]

What can I do to get rid of the empty dates? Is there something I can add to my filter?

Comment: I would probably try in this scenario something like ng-if="!EmptyDate" instead making and effort filtering I would hide the values that does not meet my criterio

Comment: @Dalorzo That sounds perfect. I'm fairly new to angular though - do you think you could post your suggestion as an answer with a bit more detail/an example? (that way I can credit you for this too)

Comment: @anwaytt ty I just shared my answer with a few more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably try in this scenario something like `ng-if="value !== EmptyValue"` instead making and effort filtering "invalid data".

One of the advantages of `ng-if` over `ng-hide` or `ng-show` it is that it removes the element entirely so this additional html is not kept on the page.

Or you could apply a second filter to your data like:

```
DateBegin in (events |filter:emptyEvents) |filter: dateFilter
```

Comment: My problem is that the DateBegin heading being displayed. (the H2 in the parent repeater) when there are no events. Any idea how I can refactor this to hiding that?

Comment: Can you show us what this object contains "DateBegin"?

Comment: Right now, it's only the value of a unique datestamp from events. So it's just a string. The only relationship between it and the events in the child repeater is that DateBegin == event.DateBegin (where event is in the child repeater). (if this doesn't make sense let me know)

Comment: Yes - wait... DateBegin is actually just a string. DateBegin == event.Datebegin

Comment: @anwyatt then my advise is to apply two filters may you will need to create a custom filter to remove empty events

Comment: I am still unable to get this working (yet) but I appreciate your advice and the time you have worked on this with me. And believe me, the reason this is unresolved is due to my ignorance - you have been great.

Comment: if you share a fiddle or plnker I will be glad to help you a bit more

Comment: I got it. see my answer for my implementation

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the "best" way, but it required the least amount of modification to my current work. I'm still going to mark Dalorzo as the accepted answer since this came from his answer, but this will show my implementation:

```
<div class="row" style="margin: 0; padding: 0" ng-repeat="DateBegin in events|groupBy:'DateBegin'|filter: dateFilter"><br />
    <div class="row tableCell" ng-repeat="event in events | filter: { DateBegin: DateBegin } | filter: search">

        <h2 ng-show="$first">{{ event.DateBegin }}</h2> <!-- this is what I added -->

        <a href="/EventDetails/{{ event.ID }}"><h1>{{ event.Name }}</h1></a>
        <p>{{ event.Description }}</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Time Begin: {{ event.TimeBegin }}</li>
            <li>Duration: {{ event.Duration }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```